# How to make Relative layout look like CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-relativelayout

I have too many Relative layout and I want to convert it that's it look like card.How I can make drawable which look like Card.I want to make it Rectangle shape like a row.

Comment: Why not wrap your relative layouts with a `CardView`?

Comment: I try to wrap but i have too many xml in my old project so it may be effect my layout alignment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card_background"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" />
```

Make one drawable named `card_background.xml`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add background to relative layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB" />
        <corners android:radius="2px" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/grey" />
        <corners android:radius="2px" />
    </shape>
</item>
```